# How to configure an alias in nginx

Tags: nginx, alias

Im switching from apache to nginx and im not sure how i would do the following in nginx.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ProxyRequests On

Alias /faq /var/www/http
<Directory /var/www/http/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ProxyPassMatch ^/faq !

ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/http.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/http.log combined
```

i currently have this but i keep getting a 404 error

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
client_max_body_size 30M;

location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}

location /faq/ {
    proxy_redirect off;
    alias /var/www/http;
    index index.php;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

}

location ~ /faq\.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

instead of `alias /var/www/http;` use `root /var/www/http;`

Also instead of if for redirection to index.php you can use:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`